# How to create a IdP with ITfoxtec

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

i am interested to create a IdP (Identity Provider) with SAML.

It´s possible to create a full IdP funcionalities with ITfoxtec Nuget?
Have any example with ASP.Net, c#?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to implement an IdP using the ITfoxtec Identity Saml 2.0 library. You can see an ASP.NET MVC core IdP example at https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test/TestIdPCore.

I have implemented the SAML 2.0 IdP part of [FoxIDs](https://www.foxids.com/docs) using the ITfoxtec Identity Saml 2.0 library.