# ITFoxtec.Identity.Saml2 - TestIdpCore - How would one add a login screen?

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

**Background:**

I've been working with the [ITFoxtec.Identity.Saml2 - TestIdpCore project](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test/TestIdPCore) to create a custom IdP.  With a little trouble I've managed to get signed/encrypted assertions working (against the [OneLogin wordpress-saml plugin](https://github.com/onelogin/wordpress-saml)).

My troubles included:

- The onelogin wordpress-saml token decryption code appears to have a bug that invalidates / breaks the assertion's signature:  [Issue #136](https://github.com/onelogin/wordpress-saml/issues/136)
- [TestIdPCore](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test/TestIdPCore) has an issue with loading private keys (at least in .NET core 6 in my environment) - [Pull Request #112](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/pull/112)
- [TestIdPCore] does not include the token encryption certificates per relying party (instead it seems to be in the Saml2 config element) - [Pull Request #113](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/pull/113)

After address the above in my environment the "trivial" example then worked:  a [hard-coded set of claims](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestIdPCore/Controllers/AuthController.cs#L269-L275) are [returned in the AuthController.Login()](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestIdPCore/Controllers/AuthController.cs#L43-L67) Action method.  I then attempted to setup an actual login (username/password) View (with a corresponding UserAuthenticationRequest model that contained a Username and Password property).

I modifying the existing Login (GET reqeuest) Action method to return a new `View("Authentication")` which displays a simple Username/Password form (tied to my new "UserAuthenticationRequest" model).

I then added a second public `async Task<IActionResult> Login(UserAuthenticationRequest request)` Action method with an `[HttpPost("Login")]` attribute as well as the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute migrating the original code from the previously existing Login() method.  However, the `Saml2RedirectBinding` class explicitly checks the Request method and throws an exception when it sees `POST` instead of `GET`:

**InvalidSaml2BindingException: Not HTTP GET Method.**

```
    ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2RedirectBinding.Read(HttpRequest request, Saml2Request saml2RequestResponse, string messageName, bool validate, bool detectReplayedTokens)
    ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2Binding<T>.ReadSamlRequest(HttpRequest request, Saml2Request saml2Request)
    MyExampleIdP.Controllers.AuthController.ReadRelyingPartyFromLoginRequest<T>(Saml2Binding<T> binding) in AuthController.cs
```

I've tried using the `Saml2PostBinding` as well but it then expects the `SAMLRequest` and `RelayState` parameters to be submitted with the Login form.

I see a few other StackOverflow posts asking how to create this login form, but there doesn't seem to be any guidance on how to overcome the above issues:

- [How to create a IdP with ITfoxtec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69224156/how-to-create-a-idp-with-itfoxtec)
- [ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 login example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69556397/itfoxtec-identity-saml2-login-example)

**My Question:**

What is the correct approach to extending `TestIdpCore` so that it can include a trivial username/password login form?  I will gladly submit another pull request to the TestIdpCore project if someone could point me in the correct direction.

Finally, thank you to ITFoxtec for developing and sharing with the community such a complete open source .NET/.NET core implementation of a SAML 2.0 library capable of both the IdP and the RelyingParty roles.

Answer (score 0):

I have the [open source project FoxIDs](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/FoxIDs) where you can see how to add a user dialog. There are a lot of things to think about depending of which security level you want to achieve.

Comment: I have looked through the FoxIDs source (actually prior to posting this question).  That said, I'm really asking:  Could you give just a little guidance on how one might receive a SAML Request (within the  context of TestIdPCore's AuthController.Login() action method) and present a view without breaking the Saml2RedirectBinding?  Should the SAMLRequest,RelayState,etc... be saved in a Session variable (server side) in order for the view to collect credentials (via HTTP POST), verify, and then redirect back to the Login() action method so that Saml2RedirectBinding "sees" an HTTP GET?

Comment: There are a lot of things to consider especially security considerations and a lot of pitfalls. There is not a short answer and I do not want to make test code on this topic because that would be misleading.

Comment: Hi, @lwg-ga have you tried out a solution?
I have the same requirement as what you try on.
I will keep trying a solution.